# Python panda filtering on

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I am trying to filter on a file so that i remain with data rows whose "Cell Name" is `LM-MP-NW-URBAN-GROCERY S & SPAZA` but when I run the above code, I get

> "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

I tried that code using a column with numbers and it worked with  `==` and `<, >` signs.

Also, please help me on how to filter on multiple items - for example in the code above, I would like to remain with all data whose cell name is `LM-MP-NW-URBAN-GROCERY S & SPAZA` or `KZN-GP-EC-URBAN_GROCERY S & SPAZA`

Thank you in advance

```
#Import libraries 
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
#Set working directory and create list of raw files 
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Shab7002\Documents\data science\18 10 9\nestle 708294\infant')
lorf = glob.glob('*.txt')
#Create empty dataframe and concatenate raw files 
df_mrgd = pd.DataFrame()

for file in lorf:
    df_add = pd.read_csv(file,sep='\t', encoding='latin-1')
    df_mrgd = pd.concat([df_mrgd, df_add.head(10)])
    #Filter columns
filt_col = ['PeriodVFP', 'Product name', 'MBD Name', 'Outlet name', 'Cell Name', 'Sales', 'SalesValue', 'SalesVolume']
#filter rows
df_filtered = df_mrgd[filt_col].query('Cell Name== "LM-MP-NW-URBAN-GROCERY S & SPAZA"')
 #and export concatenated data frame 
df_filtered.to_excel('mu.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please provide **full traceback** for your error, not just the error description.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would filter rows based on multiple `Cell Name` values in Pandas:

```
df_filtered = df_mrgd.loc[df_mrgd['Cell Name'].isin(["LM-MP-NW-URBAN-GROCERY S & SPAZA", "KZN-GP-EC-URBAN_GROCERY S & SPAZA"]), filt_col]
```

Comment: Thank you so much - i have put all filter codes I have compiled so others can refer to them - please confirm if the comments are accurate


 #filter works on numbers but not on characters
  df_filtered = df_mrgd[filt_col].query('PeriodVFP < 250')
  #filter works on characters but not on numbers
  df_filtered = df_mrgd.loc[df_mrgd['Cell Name'].isin(["GA-URBAN-GROCERY L & M", "FS-NC-URBAN-GROCERY S & SPAZA", "LM-MP-NW-URBAN-GROCERY S & SPAZA"]), filt_col]
# filter works on numbers and not characters
df_filtered = df_mrgd[(df_mrgd.PeriodVFP < 250) & (df_mrgd.OutletID == 44203)]

Comment: No, that's not correct. Your last two comments work both on characters and on numbers. I never use `query()` so I can't really comment on how to make it work with character columns.

Comment: How do i use the last comment on characters?

Comment: Just as with numerical variables, but putting the values in quotes. For instance: `df_filtered = df_mrgd[df_mrgd['Cell Name'] == 'GA-URBAN-GROCERY']`